# Comparison of 3 values? in IF,ELIF

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have school assign about IF,ELIF(and new to this web).Actually its quiet simple,but im a bit confuse because this is my first time dealing with if,i found 3 ways to type the code,
Its about program that shows index of a score.

- 100-81 = A
- 80-61 = B
- 60-0 = C

```py
score=int(input('Insert score : '))
if 100 >= score >= 81 :
    print('A')
elif 80 >= score >= 61 :
    print('B')
elif score > 100 :
    print('Doesnt exist')
else : 
    print('C')
print()

----------
score=int(input('Insert score : '))
if score > 100 :
    print('Doesnt exist')
elif score >= 81 :
    print('A')
elif score >= 61 :
    print('B')
else : 
    print('C')
```

My teacher told me that the first one is wrong,Why is it wrong?(Well,i asked to him but he didnt answer,Because im pretty sure the first one is alright)
And well the second one is more efficient,but i just dont know why the first one is wrong.
Which code is better and i should use?

Comment: The 3rd code is not doing what the first 2 codes are doing. If score = 75, it will print `A` wile the other 2 will print `B`

Comment: The first one has a typo. You are missing a closing `)` in the first line. Other than that, the first approach is the most readable way to do it in python 

Comment: Can you post the whole question. We don't know what's the result if score is 100 or 60 or 59. So we cannot determine the correctness of your code.

Comment: @ramwin, i dont think the rest of the code is needed. Using this code, we can figure out what should get printed for 100 or 60 or 59

Comment: @clmno - "The first one has a typo" they all have that typo. As Joe pointed out, the third one isn't even the same algorithm and will always produce `'A'` (assuming the maximum score is 100).

Comment: @clmno , Oh yes thanks,well i fixed it out the for the ) and the second code.So it is still ok to type the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is fine.  Python, unlike many languages, does support chained comparisons like that.  It would be wrong in C, but it's OK in Python, and it reads nicely.  The last one is wrong, because all scores will get an A.

Personally, I would write it in the opposite order:

```
    if 81 <= score <= 100:
```

because I think it reads more naturally, but it is semantically equivalent.

Comment: Yes i was thinking the same,i mean you can use that in Python,nothings wrong,even the code is still working.I even dont understand why my teacher told me that the first one is wrong.And thank you so much!